# how to format 100 non-consecutive columns in a single shot in Excel

Tags: excel, format, percentage

I'm using Excel from Office 365. I have a big spreadsheet with over 300 columns. Every third column is a percentage.

For smaller files (10 columns), I highlight every third column and click the "percentage" sign. A cell changes from .0234980 to 2.3%, for example.

Is there any way to automate highlighting every third column in a big spreadsheet so I can apply the percentage format? I can write functions and equations but don't have any ideas here.

It would be super useful. Thanks.

Comment: A vba script will be you best bet.

Comment: I would even say skip the highlighting part and just change the format outright

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional formatting for this, using the following formula:

```
=COLUMN()/3=ROUND(COLUMN()/3,0)
```

[image]
And using the desired number format (in this case "Percentage")

[image]

Comment: I like the answer. Mind you that conditional formatting is volatile and will constantly recalculate slowing down this workbook most likely :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick script to change the `NumberFormat` to percent for every third column

```
Sub PercentEveryThird()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")           'Change accordingly
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 3 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column step 3
            .Columns(i).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```